# Sorting multiple models in one view table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, view, model, controller

I have a model which has various different types of information associated with it.

```
Opportunity.rb

has_many :notes
has_many :emails
has_many :calls
```

I currently have 3 tables on the show page where in the controller I call

```
@notes = @opportunity.notes.sorted
@emails = @opportunity.emails.sorted
@calls = @opportunity.calls.sorted
```

And display them in 3 tables

I'd like to sort them chronologically so I can get a timeline.

Each one of the models has date, and I want to sort by the date then return the objects in date order.
i.e. 
The table goes:

```
Note | Content | 11-Feb | Bob
Call | Content | 07-Feb | Dave
Email | Content | 04-Feb | Steve
Call | Content | 03-Feb | Dave    
Note | Content | 01-Feb | Margaret
```

I can't work out how I merge those tables in the controller into an object I can use in the view so that I can create a table, sort on the date ("created_at") and still keep everything looking nice and clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to combine the 3 collections into an array and sort it by created_at.  In your controller:

```
@combined = (@notes + @emails + @calls).sort_by {|record| record.created_at}
```

You can then use `@combined` in your view to show the timeline.

Comment: or `sort_by(&:created_at)` for short

Comment: Yes, though that is quite a bit slower.

Comment: Yea I guess that makes sense, since this would create a proc first then run it, not sure how slow though, would have to test it.

Comment: It depends on the version of Ruby, but the speed penalty for using the to_proc shorthand can be up to an order of magnitude slower.